# var_dump retorna tudo na mesma linha

Tags: php, html5

[image: http://prntscr.com/c0esw9]

Olá pessoal meu php está retornando o `var_dump` desta forma oque pode ser?

Utilizo o xampp no ubuntu.

quem poder ajudar muito obrigado.

Comment: Tente usar: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($variavel); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provavelmente está visualizando pelo browser.

O brower renderiza o HTML. O output do `var_dump()` retorna em texto plano.
Em texto plano, a quebra de linha é \r ou \n. O browser não renderiza quebra de linha.

Para ter o visual mais amigável com quebras de linha, faça isso:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($a_sua_variavel_aqui);
echo '</pre>';
```

Isso fará com que o conteúdo seja exibido em formato texto.

Outra forma é não fazer nada. Simplesmente abra o código fonte da página. No Chrome, pressione CTRL+U.

Comment: obrigado era isso mesmo corrigiu o código , achei que era alguma coisa com o meu php ou versão , mas era apenas um código bobo rsrs obg.